# ScriptDB: How to perform a value range query? (inclusive and exclusive)

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script

I am new to scripting. I am wondering how to combine to conditionals in a query for "greater than or equal to" and "less than or equal to". Looking at Google's site I see you have the option of greaterThanOrEqualTo(value) and lessThanOrEqualTo(value) but I am wondering how you can combine them in if and/or statements. When I do this:

```
db.query({myvalue: greaterThanOrEqualTo(value),
          myvalue: lessThanOrEqualTo(value)})
```

My results ignore the first part, greaterThanOrEqualTo(value). I have done a work around using the between(value1, value2) method but I don't think it would work if I was doing an exclusive range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script DB query engine is a very simple query engine and does not have the feature you are looking for. However I can suggest an alternative, first get the MapItems using the query

```
db.query({myvalue: greaterThanOrEqualTo(value)
```

Then you need to iterate through the ScriptDbMap in the result of the query and then do an if to check for the second condition and if true push it to a final list.

Comment: So I take it there is no way to nest or combine conditionals to get what I want. If not I guess your suggestion is my only choice. Thanks.

Comment: No we cannot use conditionls for the same property, you can use AND but that is only with different properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Look at 'between'
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/script-db-instance#between(Object,Object)

Comment: Yes, I have been using a work around with the between(value1, value2) method in which I have to take the user input for the max value and increase it by one. 'Between' seems to exclude the max value. Example: If I am looking for values from 5 to 7, I have to put "between (5, 8)' inorder to include those records with a 7. I don't know how you would use the between method to exclude a range though. If there is a way to nest conditions then maybe.

Comment: For an exclusive example say everything less than 5 but greater than 7. Thanks.

Comment: less than 5 + greater than 7 = empty :) if between uses open ranges, you could do something like between 4.999999 and 7.000001. This is the AND case, for the OR in your original question, you will need to do two queries.